# Change locale in Plotly for R (thousand separator and decimal character)

Tags: r, locale, plotly

I'd like to adjust the tick labels in a plotly chart so that they would display a comma as a decimal separator and a point as a thousand separator.

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
diamonds %>% 
    mutate(cut = as.character(cut)) %>% 
    count(cut, clarity) %>%
    plot_ly(x = ~cut, y = ~n, color = ~clarity) %>% 
        layout(yaxis = list(tickformat = ",.1f"))
```

my local is already set to `"LC_COLLATE=German_Austria.1252;LC_CTYPE=German_Austria.1252;LC_MONETARY=German_Austria.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=C"`

Comment: I cannot run your code. Is it reproducible?

Comment: @Masoud you need to include `library(dplyr)`

Comment: thanks @amonk and apologies for that! `library(dplyr)` was indeed missing. @Masoud i just restarted my r session, ran the code as above and it did in fact run.

Answer (score 1):

This is an ugly answer but you can set up your object:

```
d2 <- diamonds %>% 
    mutate(cut = as.character(cut)) %>% 
    count(cut, clarity)
```

and then create the axis labels from there:

```
ticklabels <- seq(from=0, to=round(max(d2$n), digits = -3), by=1000)
```

To create a custom axis label:

```
plot_ly(d2, x = ~cut, y = ~n, color = ~clarity) %>% 
    layout(yaxis = list(tickvals = ticklabels, ticktext = paste(ticklabels/1000, ".000", ",00", sep="")  ))
```